# Why does bootstrap dropdown don't open?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page designed with Bootstrap 4.3.1 and on it a Dropdown, that doesn't open. I have included /bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css, /jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js and /bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.

When i try to open an Dropdown (even with an example from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/) I only get the following error in console: "InternalError: too much recursion" (in Firefox 75.0). Similar in Edge, just the wording of the error is "SCRIPT28: Out of stack space".

Strange thing number 1: Before some days it allready worked. I can't see anything, that I've changed, that this doesn't work anymore.

Strange thing number 2: The error occours in file /bootstrap/node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js and I don't have a folder named node_modules.

The even more strange thing number 3: When I copy the page sourcetext and save it as a html-file, all works fine.

What can I do?

Edit: Console says, the error is at popper.js:147:30 and when I click it, I get this row (if (/(auto|scroll|overlay)/.test(overflow + overflowY + overflowX)) {) in the function getScrollParent which is called recursive 4 lines later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more trying I found a solution.

I write my page in strict xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de-DE' xml:lang='de-DE' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
```

To force the browser, to interpretate the page strict with xml (all tags are correct opened and closed) I send in php this header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

When I remove this line, the dropdown works.

This seems to me to be a bug in Bootstrap. Does anyone know, how I can use both: Bootstrap and xhtml (not just write xhtml valid, also the browser to interpretate it as xml)? Can the error be reported somewhere or maybe can someone do this for me?

Edit: After some more research I found that the difference is, that node names are uppercase in html and lowercase in xml.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Writing_JavaScript_for_HTML

Sadly the team from bootstrap don't want to be compatible to xhtml.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29235

I edited the bootstrap files now locally for myself, to get it work. I hope the bootstrap team will change their opinion to this topic in future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the Popper JS file in your HTML?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

According to the docs, it's needed for dropdowns, tooltips, and popovers.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: In first try with /bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js I got the message for a missing popper.js. It works with the change to /bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js. And if there would be a script missing, the copied source code should also not work.